# como recoger la fecha de un formulario con javascript

Tags: javascript, formularios

intento recoger la información pero me da indefinido, he seguido varios pasos y siempre es lo mismo, supongo que hay uno que no llego saber cual es, si pudierais ayudarme. Porque si pongo new Date sin nada me recoge la fecha del ordenador, y si le pongo el id del input me sale como desconocido. Necesito que cada vez que se elija un día marque el día de la semana que es en letras.

```
function mostrarFecha()

{ 
  var fecha= document.getElementById("fecha").innerHTML= n;
  var d= new Date("fecha");
  var diaSemana = new Array("Domingo","Lunes","Martes","Miércoles","Jueves","Viernes","Sábado");
  var n = diaSemana[d.getDay()];
  alert ("La fecha seleccionada es " + n); 
}
```

Comment: Te invito a hacer el [tour] para que conozcas cómo funciona el sitio. También puedes mirar [ask] y [answer] para que tus preguntas tengan mejor acogida.

Comment: Si la respuesta te ayudó, por favor, márcala para que otros usuarios puedan saber que la respuesta es válida

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay varios problemas en tu función `mostrarFecha()`:

- En la asignación de la variable `fecha`, tienes una asignación de más (y `n`, salvo que sea global, será `undefined` porque no existe.
- El `new Date("fecha")` está recibiendo un parámetro no válido. Puedes leer más en [este enlace](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date).

He reproducido tu problema aquí para que cualquier usuario pueda probarlo y verificarlo:

```js
const WEEK_DAYS = [
  "Domingo", "Lunes", "Martes", "Miércoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sábado"
];

function f() {
  const d = document.querySelector('#dateFormField').value;
  const parsedDate = new Date(d);
  const dayOfWeek = parsedDate.getDay();
  document.querySelector('#currentDate').innerHTML = WEEK_DAYS[dayOfWeek];
}
```

```html
<input id="dateFormField" type="date" onchange="f()" />
<div>
  La fecha seleccionada es: <span id="currentDate">-</span>
</div>
```

Cualquier duda puedes utilizar los comentarios. Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Si la respuesta te ayudó, por favor, márcala para que otros usuarios puedan saber que la respuesta es válida

Answer (score -1):

Lo hice un poco más sencillo y también me funcionó:

```js
function mostrarFecha() {
  var fecha = new Date(document.getElementById("fecha").value);
  var dia = new Array(
    "Domingo",
    "Lunes",
    "Martes",
    "Miércoles",
    "Jueves",
    "Viernes",
    "Sábado"
  );

  alert("La fecha seleccionada es " + dia[fecha.getDay()]);
}
```

Comment: Puro código sin ninguna explicación no educa ni enseña.

Comment: si lees todo el hilo te darás cuenta que lo he puesto para mostrar que lo hice diferente a la persona que me contestó para mostrar que también lo conseguí aunque no de igual manera. Pero hay que leer... y verás que enseña lo que yo misma pregunto arriba.

Comment: Una respuesta debe ser autocontenida; no esperas a que leas todas las otras respuestas para entender la tuya.

Comment: Sólo hay una respuesta a la mía, así tanto tano no hay que leer... Y todo el mundo hace lo mismo, tampoco veo que usted aporte nada positivo, con media frase se queda tan ancho,  solo criticar por criticar. Y si a usted le molesta leer no creo que debamos seguir debatiendo el tema.